# How to show serial number or row number in Ng grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I am new to AngularJs.
I am working with ng-grid in AngularJs but I am not able to figure it out how to show serial number or row number in ng-grid.

Comment: Use index and by the way please provide your code

Comment: @ Sudarshan Thanks for you reply i have added below link for plunkr. can u please suggest how to mention sr. No.

Comment: where is link for plunker?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/UWzG0YOzXc4g8kcB6yuE?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I made a plunker that uses ng-grid's row.rowIndex property to show the row number in the first column:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zLUinDSNUS8B1IrhzYhA?p=preview

```
 $scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [
      {field: '', displayName: 'Row Number', cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText ng-scope col1 colt1" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text="">{{row.rowIndex + 1}}</span></div>'},
      {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, 
      {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **{{rowRenderIndex+1}}** property, we can easily show serial number in ng-grid UI.

```
colDef = [{
      name: 'ID',
      field: '',
      displayName: 'Id',
      cellTemplate: '<span>{{rowRenderIndex+1}}</span>',
      width: '10%'
    }, {
      field: 'data1',
      displayName: 'Data1',
      width: '40%'
    },, {
      field: 'data2',
      displayName: 'Data2',
      width: '40%'
    }]
```